# How to monitor app-usage on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Which service for iOS devices will allow me to centrally monitor app-usage, i.e. track which apps are used when and for how long?

Test scenario: Some iOS devices will be distributed to users to test applications. We would like to centrally know which apps are used when and for how long. Admin would be able to (remotely) access a dashboard and view activity for each of the enrolled devices.

Afaria (our active MDM/EMM system) can only track which apps are installed, not their usage.

http://www.qustodio.com/en/family/why-qustodio has some functionality to track/monitor apps, but somehow limited in terms of app usage detail.

Similar solution for Android are:
www.awareframework.com and 
www.ohmage.org

Monitoring via code in-app is not an option (such as www.flurry.com)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first guess, none. Since Apple is very strict on privacy they will not allow this. Nor would I as an user want this. I know there some tricks like looking at the running processes to see what apps are running. But tracking on the level you want, no. Also Strackoverflow is for programming question, software search like yours are therefor offtopic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to find a solution you desire on iOs platform as Apple is very strict about User Privacy.

For beta testing and app analytics, 2 best services are:

1. TestFlight https://www.testflightapp.com/
2. HockeyApp http://hockeyapp.net/features/

Do check them to find out if some of your use cases are present. This is it.

Comment: TestFlightApp is not accepting any new user and has been moved to iTunesConnect since Apple bought them. Plus side is that you can now have 1000 beta test via there Apple ID.